# node request module - sample request failing

Tags: node.js, npm-request

I'm currently using node 7.6.0 and am trying the npm request module 2.80.0. The module is installed via package.json npm install.  Following their simple example I immediately get: "Failed: Cannot set property 'domain' of undefined". Its a straight copy paste except for the require part.

```
var request = require('../node_modules/request/request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        });
```

Am I missing something or is there other dependencies I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why are you `require()`ing the `request` module in that way?

Comment: ^^ yeah, what he/she said. It should look more like `require('request');`

Answer (score 0):

I required it incorrectly. Should just be node_modules/request.  Confusing since there is an actual request.js inside the request folder with a module exports.

```
// Exports

Request.prototype.toJSON = requestToJSON
module.exports = Request
```